# iMac 4,1 doesn't recognise Linux Boot Mediums

Tags: linux, macos, macintosh

Not sure if this is the best place to ask, but I am not sure where else would be best!

I am trying to install some flavour of Linux (preferable Debian/Ubuntu based) on an old (2005?) iMac.

I have tried Mint 20 (xfce flavour) and Pop_OS 21 on both a bootable USB and DVD. But every time I boot (holding option), I can only select the startup disk.

I tried resetting the system boot (CMD + Option + P + R) then inserting the boot medium and pressing option on reboot, but that doesn't seem to help.

Is this an issue with older versions of MacOS? Does anyone know if there is anything else I can try?

**EDIT:** I have tried the USB drives on my wife's MacBook and they boot fine from the drive, so it seems to be an issue with the iMac, not the drive.

**ANOTHER EDIT** I managed to dig out a bootable Mac OS High Sierra USB stick, which is recognised by Mac OS Startup Manager. Comparing that stick to a Linux bootable USB, the only difference I can see is that the EFI partition is located at the start of the filesystem rather than at the end. Would that make any difference though?

Cheers,

Mo

Answer (score 1):

No, the location of the EFI System Partition should not matter.

The problem might be that the iMac 4,1 system uses a **32-bit** EFI firmware. When booting from a removable media, that means the system will be looking for `\EFI\boot\bootia32.efi` (or perhaps even just `boot.efi`, thanks @mirh!) instead of `\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi` as an x86 processor with a 64-bit UEFI firmware would do. Not every Linux distribution offers this kind of boot loader on their standard installation media.

If the iMac has the Boot Camp software available, it might have the necessary “magic” to switch the system to a BIOS-compatible mode (as if for the installation of a 32-bit version of Windows), which would allow any classic PC BIOS-style bootloaders to run.

A 32-bit firmware can still boot a 64-bit kernel, but the boot loader needs to be specifically a 32-bit EFI/UEFI one.

Comment: Interesting, so if I was to get a 32 bit distro do you think the mac would be able to boot from that? The spec of this mac is pretty old, so I cant imagine it will really benefit a huge amount from 64 bit

Comment: Oldest macs [actually used](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grub.git/commit/?id=fc8584825cb513ffaca12585657b1682ef79a3e5) `boot.efi`.